# Invert `if let ... as?` without resorting to force unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to invert next condition:

```swift
if let item = dataSource.item(at: indexPath) as? SpecificCellModel {

} else {
  // Main branch is here
}

// Where item() method signature is

func item(at indexPath) -> ModelProtocol?
```

All my logic goes into `else` and it isn't great. I also would like to refrain from using force unwrapping here. Somehow I can't wrap my head around it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `item` in your code (if it isn’t nil)?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
if !(dataSource.item(at: indexPath) is SpecificCellModel) { ...
```

Comment: I see I forgot important detail. dataSource.item() -> ModelProtocol?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this

```
if dataSource.item(at: indexPath) as? SpecificCellModel == nil {
//Main branch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use guard if have only code in if else

```
guard let item = dataSource.item(at: indexPath) as? SpecificCellModel else {
    // Main branch is here
    return
} 

// Something else.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a guard statement here

```
guard let item = dataSource.item(at: indexPath) as? SpecificCellModel  else {
// handle how you want it to
    return 
}

// Main branch is here
```